# Uncaught Error: [Ext.create] Unrecognized class name / alias

Tags: javascript, extjs, uncaught-exception

I can't figure what is going wrong with the below code. Although it is a very basic example, it drives me crazy since it is saying "Uncaught Error: [Ext.create] Unrecognized class name / alias" error in the console.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../ext5/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
Ext.define('SessionModel',{
                extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
                fields: [
                    {name : 'id', type: 'int'}, 
                    {name : 'title', type: 'string'},
                    {name : 'sessionLevel', type: 'int'},
                    {name : 'approved', type: 'bool', defaultValue: false}
                ],
                requires: ['Ext.data.validator.Validator'],
                validators: [
                    {type: 'length', field: 'title', min: 3},
                    {type: 'inclusion', field: 'sessionLevel', list: [1, 2, 3]}
                ]
            });

            var session1 = Ext.create('SessionModel',{
                title: 'Object Oriented Javascript',
                sessionLevel : 2
            });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
```

Can someone help what's going wrong in the above block?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Try wrapping all of this code inside `Ext.onReady(function() {});`

Comment: Hi @arthurakay Thanks for the suggestion, However I've already tried that, But no luck :(

Comment: I placed your code in a [sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/acf) and it appears to work correctly.  What version of extjs are you using?

Comment: Guys, Finally I have figured it out. I'm using a commercial version of ExtJS which might have expired already. Trying the same code in a GPL version did the trick!

Sencha folks can still display an apt message rather than these meaningless console logs.